# Can't find open when starting npm start (ENOGIT git is not installed)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to install bower as I am setting up a development environment on my laptop.

I installed git using the `npm install` procedure but it reports wrong operating system.
I used `npm remove git` and it appeared to remove it and then I installed git for windows.

Even though I apparently removed git it still reports wrong operating system.

Has anyone got a foolproof way of installing a nodejs environment on a windows 10 PC, as I have been trying for days without success?

Here is the message:

```
C:\javatest>bower install
bower jasmine-core#^2.5.2       ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH
```

What `ENOGIT` mean?
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, git needs to be installed and should be added to PATH ( which is an Environment System Variable)

[ When you install git, there's an option to add it to PATH in the installation steps ]

if you want to add to PATH after git installation please follow these steps:

- From Start search for **Advanced System Settings**
- Open **Environment Variables**
- In **System Variables** section, search for **Path**, select it and choose **Edit**
- Click **New**, and add the path to git cmd, (ex: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd")

Comment: Made the classic mistake! Did not reboot after installing Git!

Comment: However I still have an error! it still can't find module 'Open'!  Where is this module normally loaded, with what installation?